# C# Get all types from referenced libraries

Tags: reflection, .net-core

I'm trying to build a dependency management tool. So I need to get all the classes from all the libraries.

There are three projects written in C#, .NET Core 3.0.

- ProjectA
- ProjectB
- ProjectC

ProjectA is an executable console app.

And ProjectA references ProjectB. ProjectB references ProjectC.

> ProjectA -> ProjectB -> ProjectC

For code in ProjectC:

```cs
// In ProjectC
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
// That can list all classes in ProjectC.
```

And for code in ProjectC:

```cs
// In ProjectC
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes()
// That can list all classes in ProjectA.
```

But how can I list all classes in ProjectB? (Code in ProjectC, run by ProjectA)

Comment: If you have a type that is know to be present in each one of these assemblies, get it and get the assembly from there, like: `typeof(TypeContainedInAssemblyB).Assembly)`.

Comment: @thehennyy Yeah, that was a solution. Thank you. But I am trying to build a library which doesn't know what class it may reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a solution:

Just start building a dependency tree from entry assembly:

```cs
// Code this in project C. Run this by project A.

// Entry is A.
var entry = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

entry
    // This will get B and C with type: `AssemblyName`
    .GetReferencedAssemblies()
    // Load assembly B and C.
    .Select(t => Assembly.Load(t))
    // Get all class in B and C.
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
    .ToList();
```

The way to get referenced assemblies is:

`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` Method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies?view=netframework-4.8